# Couchdb illegal_database_name error when creating database

Tags: linux, erlang, couchdb

Deployed couchdb with erlang v25 on my custom linux distribution and I am not able to create any database other than system databases (_replicator and _users)

Init system - busybox inittab;
Linux Kernel - 5.15.35;
Filesystem (/data) - ext4 on sdcard
couchdb - 3.3.3
erlang/Opt - 25.3.2.8

[image]

The errors when running manually show illegal_database_name when initiating database creation.

```
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:08:15.132819Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.604.0> 5f6e973f16 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin PUT /database 201 ok 97
[error] 1970-01-01T00:08:15.137693Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.336.0> -------- mem3_shards tried to create shards/00000000-7fffffff/database.495, got {error,{illegal_database_name,<<"shards/00000000-7fffffff/database.495">>}}
[error] 1970-01-01T00:08:15.144731Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.336.0> -------- mem3_shards tried to create shards/80000000-ffffffff/database.495, got {error,{illegal_database_name,<<"shards/80000000-ffffffff/database.495">>}}
[error] 1970-01-01T00:08:15.148246Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.605.0> cd950a0564 req_err(26532023) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
```

My configuration only overrides local.ini with:

```
admin = mypassword
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

and default.ini with:

```
database_dir = /data/database
view_index_dir = /data/views
```

Full log when creating database

```
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.614808Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.685.0> 7940a97192 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin PUT /new 201 ok 29
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.626010Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.336.0> -------- mem3_shards tried to create shards/00000000-7fffffff/new.1390, got {error,{illegal_database_name,<<"shards/00000000-7fffffff/new.1390">>}}
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.629318Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.336.0> -------- mem3_shards tried to create shards/80000000-ffffffff/new.1390, got {error,{illegal_database_name,<<"shards/80000000-ffffffff/new.1390">>}}
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.632138Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.686.0> 96b808b482 req_err(26532023) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
    [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L134">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L149">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L220">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L109">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>]
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.634025Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.686.0> 96b808b482 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin GET /new/_all_docs?startkey=%22_design%2F%22&endkey=%22_design0%22&include_docs=true&limit=501 500 ok9
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.645236Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.686.0> dd08b02042 req_err(26532023) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
    [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L134">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L149">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L220">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L109">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>]
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.646807Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.686.0> dd08b02042 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin GET /new 500 ok 8
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.647653Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.687.0> eec415c79f req_err(26532023) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
    [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L134">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L149">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L220">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L109">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>]
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.648820Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.688.0> e1cbdfc980 req_err(26532023) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
    [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L134">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L149">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L220">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L109">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>]
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.649194Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.687.0> eec415c79f 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin GET /new 500 ok 9
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:23:10.650398Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.688.0> e1cbdfc980 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin GET /new/_all_docs?skip=0&limit=21 500 ok 9
[error] 1970-01-01T00:23:11.043960Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.686.0> 9371a72db0 req_err(26532023) internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened.
    [<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L134">>,<<"fabric_util:get_shard/4 L149">>,<<"fabric:get_security/2 L220">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:db_authorization_check/1 L109">>,<<"chttpd_auth_request:authorize_request/1 L19">>]
[notice] 1970-01-01T00:23:11.046016Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.686.0> 9371a72db0 192.168.0.1:5984 192.168.0.20 admin GET /new/_all_docs?startkey=%22%22&endkey=%22%E9%A6%99%22&limit=30 500 ok 8
```

1. Could this be a misconfiguration issue?
2. Is there any limitation about the filesystem I am not aware of?
3. Is there a minimum hardware requirements for CouchDB?
4. Any other reason that crated database is not accessible?

Comment: The issue was unset linux system time, if anyone ever wonders here. Jus manually setting system time with `date -s '2024-02-16 12:34:56'` solved the issue